# Our Magento account was hacked; files deleted; hosting company is unable to restore

Tags: magento-1.9, security

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
Managed VPS from Hostforweb
CentOS 7.x/WHM / Cpanel
```

We got hacked. Files were deleted and our site was and is down. I have a full cPanel backup which I made available to our hosting company (I gave them the last 2 I made) in order for them to restore the site to the way it was before the hack. It's been more than 20 hours now and it has not been restored yet. They tried to restore it but the site loads all broken (without images etc.) and they sent me this:

---

*The uploaded backups do not contain the Magento installation.
However, I was able to gather some missing parts from the provided backups and forged a loading frontend:
https://www.ourdomain.com/index.php/
This website is still damaged and you have to proceed with a manual migration of the store to a fresh Magento installation. We do not provide such service, but you can hire a seasoned Magento web developer who will take care of the transition.
The store was hacked and the cPanel account infected due to security exploits found in this outdated Magento version.*

---

We would like to continue running the same (1.9.1) version of Magento though because we tried the new 2.x version and it does not really run well on this server.

I do have another backup of the HTML files and the database I made some time back via Cpanel as well as all the files I just downloaded via FTP.

How to restore our site? **What is the best course of action forward?**

---

**UPDATED on October 19th, 2018:**

**The hosting company restored the front page *perfectly* now but when I click on most of the products - it gives the following Error: 
404 error: Page not found. (showing on a generic Magento page with Magento logo and Magento colors)**

[image]

---

NEW update on October 19th, 2018:

The hosting company keeps trying to install this.

We now have the following Error on the front page:

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'product_product.mg_core_url_rewrite' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mg_core_url_rewrite` AS `rewrite` WHERE (request_path IN ('', '/')) AND (id_path LIKE 'category/%')

Trace:
#0 /home/product/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/product/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/product/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/product/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/product/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/product/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/product/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(1355): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/product/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(361): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->isCategoryPage()
#8 /home/product/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(411): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getNormalizedUrl()
#9 /home/product/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(778): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getCacheKey()
#10 /home/product/public_html/app/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(1407): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->fetch()
#11 /home/product/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(687): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->extractContent(false)
#12 /home/product/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest()
#13 /home/product/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/product/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}

Error log record number: 1076426995669
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry to hear that. It's always a hassle. 
First of all, any files you downloaded after the hack cannot be trusted.
They might be infected.

If you have a backup I'd suggest to work from that. A Magento developer should be able to tell you what is in there and what might be missing.
This can be supplemented either from a vanilla Magento installation or will need the re-importing of products and images.

For your database as well, I'm afraid you will lose some orders. Best to restore to the latest version from before the hack.

Regarding the hosting; I'm not sure what the knowledge of Magento is within the hosting company but I expect it's low. Although it will be more expensive I can recommend looking at a hosting company that has a little bit more knowledge of Magento as they would be able to help you faster in the future.

Very import: even when you restore your shop; the leak is still there. This has to be fixed.

Comment: What is a full cPanel backup good for then? I thought it has all the HTML files and the database and you can just unzip it and restore it back the way it was when the backup was made?

Comment: @Allysin as far as I know that should be exactly that. However, I do not know how the hosting company set this up

Comment: I did the install through Softaculous back in the day...it's just bunch of HTML files connecting to a database, isn't it? Can you please see my update in the original ticket?

Answer (score 0):

What error shows up when you initially found out the attack? I think the error will reveal if it was just a few core files or templates than can be restored from a public copy?

Comment: It was just showing a directory structure on the screen. Folders not relevant to Magento. No Error message.

Comment: Any screenshot?

Comment: @ Richard Feraro I think I copied the folder names and saved it on the local machine but I'm not on there now...I remember there was the Magento Connect folder that I renamed to something really strange long time before because I didn't want people attacking that. The hosting company restored the front page perfectly now but when I click on most of the products - it gives the following Error: 404 error: Page not found. (with a generic Magento page)

Comment: Try checking if there is a file .htaccess in the Magento root directory. It is a hidden file and it handles the URL redirects.